# How do I add random spotting to the same face in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I would like to add random spotting to the same face to decrease the amount of vertices needed. Take this Dalmatian for example, suppose its body was only made up of 12 faces. I would like to avoid making a texture as my actual model is more complicated. The spots are only one colour and the surrounding area is only one colour. How could I do this in cycles?

[image]

I would also like to know how to control the amount of spots produced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can procedurally generate such a texture and apply it to the mesh. This is not a lot of work and can get you some basic results going quickly.

The basic idea is that you take a predetermined mathematical function which assigns each point in space a value. Then you use those values as a color input. Blender makes this quite intuitive. This is what the node setup looks like:

[image: The material]

The color ramp controls the dimensions of the spots, and you can mess around with the values of the Musgrave Texture to achieve different looks. The ones I used procuduced this result:

[image: The dog]

You can tweek the size of the spots with the "Scale" parameters, and their general shape with the color ramp. Hit me up if you have any further questions.

Comment: Works great! thank you. Do you also know how to control the amount of spots produced?

Comment: @user49936 Try fiddling with Detail and Lacunarity on the musgrave

Comment: I can see how that would work but it's not helping my model. Any other suggestions? Thanks again

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly you try to find a procedural way to make some black and white spots on yout object. Here is a way to do it:

- Make the following node chain : *Texture Coordinate* (*Object* output) > *Voronoi Texture* > *ColorRamp* > *Diffuse BSDF* > *Material Output*. With the *Voronoi* you will create the spots shapes and sizes and with the *ColorRamp* you will determine the space between the spots.
- But as you can see the spots are a little bit too regular. If you want to introduce more accidents, before the *Voronoi* you can add a *Color* node > *MixRGB* (*Add* mode) and plug a *Noise Texture* on its other socket. This solution was inspired by [Gleb Alexandrov's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liNGmdXsfbs).

[image]