# Add noise to mask texture

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine, skybox

I am trying to recreate in Blender some space scene like the one of this image
[image]

So far, I wanted to create some "clouds/nebulae" that they are somehow "circular" in a given region of the space (Environment texture), so I am using a mask for that like this (so the noise texture is only applied here)

[image]

However, I would like to add some "noise" to the edge of that texture so its not that sharp and it adds some randomness to it. Basically, I would like to get something like this (done in photoshop)
[image]

How could I get something similar using Nodes in Blender?

Answer (score 5):

If as mentioned in the question this is for an **environment texture**, we need to have a way to tune *where* the disk/shape will be displayed in the sky:

[image]

A possibility is to calculate the length from 2 coordinates (here X and Z), transform it eventually (square root for instance, optional) and filter using a color ramp. The length from (X,Z) is easier to tune/place than a gradient texture.

The shape orientation in the sky can be defined using a mapping node and its rotations.

The perturbation is given by a musgrave/noise combination (for instance) which displaces a bit the input coordinates.

[image]

Playing with it a bit (three settings of this kind) and mixing colors (still as world node tree):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could mix a *Gradient* (in *Spherical* mode) and a *Noise Texture* through a *MixRGB* (in *Multiply* mode), add a *Musgrave Texture* before the *Gradient* to disturb its roundness a bit:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh that's a nice trick using Musgrave to disturb the coordinates :).

Comment: thanks, I originally learnt it from this tuto by Gleb Alexandrov: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liNGmdXsfbs... allows you to make more natural spots: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136986/how-do-i-add-random-spotting-to-the-same-face-in-cycles