# Procedural dot material

Tags: texturing, procedural

Is there a way to procedurally make dots on my mesh just as shown in the images below?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: May I recommend to read this : [How do I add random spotting to the same face in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136986) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add random spotting to the same face in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136986/how-do-i-add-random-spotting-to-the-same-face-in-cycles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I already made this, before seeing Stef's duplicate report, here's the Blender 4.0 version, pretty much the same as Moonboots' answer:

[image]

[image]

Consider also using the 2D UV version: (and notice the seam)

[image]

Comment: While this is definetely close to what Id like, I do wonder if it's possible to get a bit more control over the overall shape and placement of the dots as well as getting a random scale for each of them ?

Comment: @infinitynoobie if you want control, just use texture paint, painting circles can't be hard

Comment: You're right, imma do this. Thanks for the help!